# How to initialize multidimensional arrays for using Julia's ncread() on the same variable in different files?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia, netcdf

I am using the NetCDF package in Julia 0.5.0 to read in the same multidimensional variable from ~10 different netcdf files. Is there a better way to loop through the files and consolidate them into one overarching multidimensional array rather than creating an array of arrays like I currently have?

Currently, my code is set up like:

```
files = ["file1", "file2", "file3", ... , "file10"] 
#length(files) = 10

var = Array{Array}(10)

for i in collect(1:1:10)
    var[i] = ncread(files[i], "x")
end
```

where

```
size(var) = 10

size(var[1]) = (192,59,193) #from file1
.
.
.
size(var[10]) = (192,59,193) #from file10
```

which works, but is not the desired format because I later want to take averages along Dimension Y in what are currently sub-arrays. Ideally, I would like to use `ncread()` to read `x` into one multidimensional array `var`, such that the size looks like

```
size(var) = (10,192,59,193)
```

where

```
var[1,:,:,:] #from file1
.
.
.
var[10,:,:,:] #from file10
```

I think that `hcat()` or `push!()` might be needed, but I'm not sure how to initialize the multidimensional arrays before the for-loop to account for `ncread()` output? I have to do this for ~8 variables in the files, and I don't know the dimensions or lengths of the different variables prior to calling `ncread()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
filenames = ["file$i" for i = 1:10]; # make some filenames
ncread(filename) = rand(2,3,4) # define a dummy function similar to yours

a = ncread(filenames[1]) # read the first file to get the size
output = Array{Float64}(length(filenames),size(a)...); #preallocate the full array, lookup splatting to see how this works
output[1,:,:,:] = a # assign the data we already read
for i in 2:length(filenames) # read and assign the rest
    output[i,:,:,:] = ncread(filenames[i])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

NCO uses [ncecat](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncecat) for this:

```
ncecat in*.nc out.nc
```

However, doing so much with so little code may cause your head to explode.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for since I am ultimately creating composite analyses, but is there a way to thin out unnecessary variable dimensions when calling `ncecat`? I am compositing axisymmetric analyses that have an unnecessary azimuth and time dimension, and it would be nice to reduce the output file size upfront.

Comment: If the dimensions are "unnecessary" then they are what I call degenerate, i.e., of size 1, and take up no extra space. Degenerate and non-degenerate dimensions can also averaged-over (with ncwa) or hyperslabbed (with -d) prior to concatentation as described in the manual.